# Mostrar Imágenes table view controller con la Librería AlamofireImage Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode, alamofireimage, uitableviewcontroller

Estoy realizando una app que funciona como lector de feeds.

Tengo un `UITableViewController`, en el que muestro todas las noticias que leo de un xml, muestro el título, la fecha, una breve descripción y una imagen. Menos la imagen, todo lo muestro correcto.

He añadido la librería `AlamofireImage` para que se visualicen las imágenes. En un primer momento no aparecen, pero si recargo la vista con un `reloadData()`, las imágenes aparecen.

La mayoría de las imágenes se ven en su posición correcta, pero otras se salen de su posición y en algunas, solo sale imagen. El título, la fecha y la descripción ni aparecen.

Si a las imágenes les pongo un ancho y un alto fijo, aparece perfectamente, pero si solo las posiciono por constraints, es cuadno aparece ele error, que tardan en cargar

Os dejo el código que utilizo:

```
if let actualImageView = imageView {
// actualImageView.load(currentArticleToDisplay.imagen)
/*let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string:currentArticleToDisplay.imagen)
    let imageRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(imageRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response, data, error) in
    actualImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    //actualImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
  })*/
  actualImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

  let URL = NSURL(string: currentArticleToDisplay.imagen)!

  actualImageView.af_setImageWithURL(
     URL,
     placeholderImage: nil,
     filter: nil
  )
  //actualImageView.frame = view.bounds
  //actualImageView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

  //actualImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
}
```

Las constraints, las tengo definidas en el `Main.storyboard`, porque si las ponía en código, tampoco me cargaban en un primer momento.

¿Alguna idea de cual puede ser el problema?
¿Hace falta que añada mas partes del código?
¿Es esta la forma correcta de mostrar imágenes?
¿Hay alguna libreria con la que lo pueda solucionar?

Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usar `AlamofireImage` es correcto, solo que no estás tomando en cuenta que las peticiones se realizan de forma **asíncrona**; esa es la razón por lo que la primera vez *'no aparecen'* las imágenes, ya que aún no han terminado de cargar cuando invocas:

```
if let actualImageView = imageView {
    // ...
}
```

Lo cual evidentemente devuelve `nil` y no se realiza hasta que vuelves a ejecutar `reloadData()`, que por otro lado, ni si quiera es necesario que manualmente actualices la tabla con `reloadData()` ya que `AlamofireImage` actualiza la `UIImageView` cuando ha terminado de descargarla.

No tengo claro en donde estas realizando la asignación de la imagen así que supondré que lo haces en el método delegado `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, de ahí que te comparto el siguiente código de muestra que realiza lo que tu quieres con contenido *Dummy*:

```
import UIKit
import AlamofireImage

class DummyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myAwesomeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myAwesomeLabel: UILabel!
}

class MyAwesomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let numberOfCells: Int = 100

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfCells
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DummyCell
        cell.myAwesomeLabel.text = "My awesome label \(indexPath.row)"

        let imageURL = NSURL(string: "http://placehold.it/100?text=Image%20\(indexPath.row)")!

        cell.myAwesomeImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        cell.myAwesomeImage.af_setImageWithURL(imageURL, placeholderImage:nil)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
}
```

Cuando las imágenes terminen de descargarse, estas se desplegarán en el lugar asignado. También podrías sustituir:

```
cell.myAwesomeImage.af_setImageWithURL(imageURL, placeholderImage:nil)
```

por

```
let placeHolder = UIImage(named: "placeHolder.png")
cell.myAwesomeImage.af_setImageWithURL(imageURL, placeholderImage:placeHolder)
```

Donde `"placeHolder.png"` es una imagen que tendrías en tu proyecto y que se mostrará mientras terminan de descargarse las imágenes reales.

Comment: Gracias, lo probare haber si me soluciona el problema!

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo problema y el placeholder no aparece, en que ruta lo tengo que poner?? @lech-h-conde

Comment: El problema, creo que no es ese, si defino un ancho y un alto fijo, aparece perfecto, pero si no lo defino es cvuando da el error!!

Comment: Perdón por la respuesta tardía @AlbertoMier, he estado muy ocupado. El `placeholder` se muestra si tienes la imagen en tu proyecto, impórtala en tus `Images.xcassets` para que la puedas ocupar en cualquier parte de tu código. También tienen que ver las medidas, a cualquier view se le tiene que asignar posición `x`, posición `y`, ancho y alto (`width`, `height`) para que se muestre, o reglas adecuadas si estas utilizando `Autolayout` lo que te recomiendo mucho; lo puedes hacer con código (`CGRectMake`) o desde el `Interface Builder`. Es muy sencillo y hay mucha información en la red. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es importante saber que los `UItableView` reutilizan celdas y que por tanto es importante que la instancia de `UIImageView` no debería ser la misma.
La forma correcta es que implementes el método delegado tal que así:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // [...] <- Código previo de la celda

    // Image
    let URL = NSURL(string: currentArticleToDisplay.imagen)!

    cell.actualImageView.af_setImageWithURL(
        URL,
        placeholderImage: nil,
        filter: nil
    )

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Me da este error: `Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'actualImageView'`

Comment: actualImageView debe ser una propiedad de la celda

Comment: He empezado hace poco con swift, como puedo añadirlo como propiedad de la celda?

Comment: Pero donde tienes añadida la imagen? La imagen debe estar en la celda, sino no la podras utilizar

Comment: Esta dentro de la celda en el Main.storyboard

Comment: Pues crea un IBOutlet de la imagen a la celda para poder acceder a la imagen

Comment: Eso si lo tengo, de esta forma: `let imageView: UIImageView? = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView?`

Comment: Cambiale el nombre (ya que la celda ya tiene una propiedad con ese nombre) y usala despues como te he dicho

Comment: me sigue saliendo el mismo error que al principio

Comment: Solo aparecen las imagenes al hacer reloadData()

Comment: Cuantos reloads haces en total? 1 reload como minimo es necesario

Comment: Solo hago un reload cuando hago scroll hacia arriba para activar el `refreshControl`

Comment: Es necesario un `reloadData` justo después de rellenar los datos origen del `UITableView`. Y ya después haces el reload con el `refreshControl`

Comment: Ya lo he añadido, cuadno termina el parser de leer el xml pero sigue sin funcionar @mhergon